# How much of the following vitamins would result in a vitamin overdose?

Tags: toxicity, overdose, multi-vitamin

I drink a shed load of the energy drink 'Monster Energy.' Each single 500 ml can contains:

B2 3.5mg

B3 43mg

B6 4.0mg

B12 13ug

I drink around 4 of these within a 3 hour period every day. How likely would a vitamin overdose be in these circumstances?

Comment: Every 4 hours or just one 4 hours in a day.  It is loaded with sugar and sodium and you are worried about the vitamins?

Comment: And the cost? Why are you drinking all that crap in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps to emphasize the definition of vitamins:

> The vitamins are a disparate group of compounds; they have little in
>   common either chemically or in their metabolic functions.
>   Nutritionally, they form a cohesive group of organic compounds that
>   are required in the diet in **small amounts (micrograms or milligrams
>   per day)** for the maintenance of normal health and metabolic integrity.
>   They are thus differentiated from the essential minerals and trace
>   elements (which are inorganic) and from essential amino and fatty
>   acids, which are required in larger amounts.

Below is a table showing the RDAs for named vitamins:

[image]

I compiled this tablet with information obtained from these sites:

- [Vitamins and minerals](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/vitamins-and-minerals/vitamin-b/)
- [Vitamins and Minerals: How Much Should You Take?](https://www.webmd.com/vitamins-and-supplements/vitamins-minerals-how-much-should-you-take)

While it may seem you are well under the upper tolerable limits, continuing this habit will eventually results in toxicity over a long period of time.
Bear in mind these micronutrients are needed in trace amounts and over-accumulation will inevitably introduce adverse effects.

Actually (as suggested in comments) you should be more concerned with the other minerals/components you are over consuming namely sodium and sugar. These surely will precipitate other conditions like organ damage, increased blood pressure, renal damage cardiovascular disease etc and you should be equally concerned as with the vitamins.

Acknowlegements

- [Why is the Vitamin B complex, a “complex”?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/75234/41890)